# How to properly check type of error returned by plugin.Open

Tags: go

I would like to know how can I check the type of error returned by plugin.Open, e.g:

```
package main

import "plugin"

func main() {
  _, err := plugin.Open("./module.so")
  // here
}
```

I would like to do something different if the error is:

```
plugin.Open("./module.so"): realpath failed
```

Which basically means that the file doesn't exist.

Example of desired result:

```
package main

import "plugin"

func main() {
  _, err := plugin.Open("./module.so")
  if err.Error() == "plugin.Open(\"./module.so\"): realpath failed" {
    // do something different here
  } else {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

The string that I pass to `plugin.Open` can have other values, so it needs to be something more smart than that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only interested in check if the file exists, you can use [https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#IsNotExist)

Comment: @Motakjuq not on that error, no.

Answer (score 3):

Inspection of [the code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ce536837d8e53f1bf0c7ef450d4580d19f7d6f52/src/plugin/plugin_dlopen.go#L46-L50) for `plugin.Open()` reveals the package calls out to some C code to determine whether the path exists. If it doesn't, it returns a plain error value. In particular, the package does not define any sentinel errors which you can compare against, nor does it return its own concrete implementer of the `error` interface which carries custom metadata. This is the code which produces that error:

```golang
return nil, errors.New(`plugin.Open("` + name + `"): realpath failed`)
```

`errors.New` is a basic implementation of the `error` interface which doesn't allow any additional information to be passed. Unlike other locations in the standard library which return errors (such as path non-existent errors from the `os` package), you can't get such metadata in this instance.

---

## Check whether the module file exists first

My preference would be to verify whether the module exists *before* attempting to load it, using the native capabilities provided by the `os` package:

```golang
modulePath := "./module.so"
if _, err := os.Stat(modulePath); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    // Do whatever is required on module not existing
}

// Continue to load the module – can be another branch of the if block
// above if necessary, depending on your desired control flow.
```

## Compare a subset of the error values

You could also use `strings.Contains` to search for the value `realpath failed` in the returned error value. *This is not a good idea* in the event that string changes in future, so if you adopt this pattern, at the very least you should ensure you have *rigorous tests around it* (and even then it's still not great).

```golang
_, err := plugin.Open("./module.so")
if err != nil {
    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "realpath failed") {
        // Do your fallback behavior for module not existing
        log.Fatalf("module doesn't exist")
    } else {
        // Some other type of error
        log.Fatalf("%+v", err)
    }
}
```